# C++ Socket listener accept() didn't accept connection request when in release

Tags: c++

I created a TCP Server(runs on PC) and a Client(runs on a Android Tablet). Something strange happens on the Server one when accept connection request.

1. When i run the debug one, it works perfectly.
2. when i run the release one, it works when i connect to the WIFI which I've been on while i'm coding it.  but when i changed the Wifi(because i need to place my server PC at different place), the server didn't catch my connection request.

i used wireshark, and confirmed that the request has arrived my server PC. destination port is 9090.
and also checked the netstat, confirmed that my port 9090 be opened by my application.
I searched the internet for a whole day, and didn't find any relevant answers.
could you have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Here is my server code.

```
int StartServer() {
  WSADATA wsaData;
  int iResult;

  struct addrinfo * result = NULL;
  struct addrinfo hints;

  int iSendResult;
  char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
  int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

  // Initialize Winsock
  iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), & wsaData);
  if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
  }

  ZeroMemory( & hints, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

  // Resolve the server address and port
  iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, & hints, & result);
  if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
  }

  // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
  listenSocket = socket(result - > ai_family, result - > ai_socktype, result - > ai_protocol);
  if (listenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
  }

  // Setup the TCP listening socket
  iResult = bind(listenSocket, result - > ai_addr, (int) result - > ai_addrlen);
  if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(listenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
  }

  freeaddrinfo(result);

  iResult = listen(listenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
  if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(listenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When in main function:

```
//start the server
if ((ret = StartServer()) > 0)
{
    cout << "Start server failed!" << endl;
    cin >> ret;
    return 0;
}
    cout << "*************************************" << endl;
    cout << "waiting for connection" << endl; 
    SOCKET clientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;//create client socket
    clientSocket = accept(listenSocket, NULL, NULL); 
    cout << "connection confirmed!" << endl;
```

Comment: You `bind` the listening socket to a specific IP address. The connection probably arrives on a different address. Try binding to `INADDR_ANY` instead, to listen on all adapters.

Comment: Please format this illegible mess properly.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik , thanks a lot for your comment. i checked the netstat -ano,  TCP         0.0.0.0:9090           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11952 exists in the list. so i think i'm now listening to the 0.0.0.0:9090, right?

Answer (score -1):

i finally solved the problem. but don't get why!

i copied my source code to a new project, and set the settings as i did before. 
and when i release this one, it worked!

i tested on several different Wifi, every one can work fine.

but don't know why=======